# How to view contents of .adapter file in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am trying to view the contents of an `.adapter` file in the `bin` directory of Worklight's Eclipse, is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .adapter file is just a .zip file. Rename the extension to .zip and extract it. You will then be able to review the contents of the archive.